# Filtering data that will only filter based on if it matches with the first few letters instead of matching everything

Tags: google-sheets

From a list of items that have been sold, I am trying to filter out who sold what based on the unique ID number everyone is using on the item.

For example:

Worker 1 Unique ID- Naya

Worker 2 Unique ID- Rena

Worker 3 Unique ID- Ken

So everything they sell will have the unique ID + "0001".

For Example:
Naya0001, Naya0002, Rena0007, Ken0103, Ken1101, Ken0001 and so on

The issue I'm running into is that I am trying to use the starting words and emit the number part on my drop down table

Drop-down menu: Naya, Rena, Ken

The Main data is in a sheet called "YApr-22". And I am using the formula

=FILTER('YApr-22'!A3:AF700,'YApr-22'!I3:I700=J1)  #to pull the data onto another sheet.

The formula works if I input the numbers as well. Like if I look for "Rena0007" instead of just "Rena".

Is there any workaround or another solution to this where only the name of the person will be cross-checked if data exists and pulled so I can see all the different variations of sales made by the same person?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Can you please provide a sample dataset for this?

Comment: The solution at the bottom solved my problem, but if you would still like I can provide a link for that.

Comment: Here is the link - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nqm8-P8wUrKuOLTYV1QKQCHquszjD8JLgE7ZyfWXg_0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, try this:

`=FILTER('YApr-22'!A3:AF700,REGEXMATCH('YApr-22'!I3:I700,"(?i)"&J1))`

-or-

`=FILTER('YApr-22'!A3:AF700,REGEXMATCH(LOWER('YApr-22'!I3:I700),LOWER(J1)))`

The inclusion of `(?i)` or `LOWER` is to add a measure of error proofing, so that, "ken" matches "KEN" or "Ken." Some functions are case agnostic, but REGEX is inherently not.

Comment: @Eric Tyler The 'regexmatch' function solved my problem, but you make a good point regarding the lowercase & uppercase matching issue that I did not consider. Thank you.

Comment: Happy to hear it. Please take a moment to mark my solution post as "Best Answer." This alerts the volunteer community here that the issue has been solved, and it allows future site visitors to quickly find the answers that are most relevant to their own needs and searches.

Comment: @Eric Tyer, Sorry to ask, but how do I mark your solution as "Best Answer"? Is that a feature where you need more reputation points to do? Cause I do not see any feature.

Comment: Thanks for following up. Everyone should be able to do that, as it is a core function of this site. There should be a checkmark you can check (which only you, the poster, can see) somewhere within what you see of my post.